# How can I remove mutations from a callback chain?

Tags: javascript, callback, functional-programming, side-effects, mutation

I'm trying to wrap my head around storing state with functional programming.

I wrote a function that has both mutations and side-effects; although, does include some encapsulation. How can I represent this same functionality with functional programming?

```js
const createCallbackChain = () => {
  let callbacks = []

  const addCallback = callback => (
    callbacks
    .push(callback)
  )

  const triggerCallbacks = data => (
    callbacks
    .forEach(callback => callback(data))
  )

  return (
    Object.freeze({
      addCallback,
      triggerCallbacks,
    })
  )
}

const callbackChain = createCallbackChain()

callbackChain.addCallback(() => console.log('Hello'))
callbackChain.addCallback(() => console.log('World!'))

callbackChain.triggerCallbacks()
```

My goal is to be able to call `addCallback` at separate times and trigger all callbacks as many times as I want. There is no need for a `removeCallback` nor is there a need to add callbacks after a `trigger` has occurred.

Comment: Looks a bit like a poor man's promise or observable.

Comment: Callbacks without side effects are rather useless, unless you make `triggerCallback` return their result values and have the caller use that somehow.

Comment: I'm actually trying to capture the Observable create function and call an `observer.next` when a matching Express route callback is called. I'm exporting the `triggerCallbacks` function directly from my middleware modules.

Comment: i'd look at something like [rxjs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) for some ideas

Comment: I'm using RxJS. I was hoping I could ask a general question and the apply the answer to observables. As it stands, I might have to write a new one specific to my Rx.Observable use case.

Answer (score 1):

You need create functions for process certain data. Array of callbacks in your case. We can write our function without closure, and pass our callbacks as arguments.

```
const triggerCallbacks = (callbacks, data) => callbacks
  .forEach(callback => callback(data));

const addCallback = (callbacks, callback) => callbacks.concat([callback]);

const calbackChainDefault = [];

const withHelloCallback = addCallback(calbackChainDefault, () => console.log('Hello'));
const withWorldCallback = addCallback(withHelloCallback, () => console.log('World!'));

triggerCallbacks(withHelloCallback, null); //print "Hello"
triggerCallbacks(withWorldCallback, null); //print "Hello World"
```

Comment: If you interested in functional programming pay attention to Sunctuary.JS or Rmada.JS libraries.

Comment: JavaScript `.concat()` can take functions and will add it to the end of the array. You don't need to wrap it.

Comment: It my own preference. I think that functions always should have only one interface. And always use more common case.